# How to prove a function is continuous on a metric space by the theorems about continuity on a point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I'm asking for some hints or direction for my homework of proving a function is continuous on a metric space. I was given this homework after the lecture about the continuity of functions on a point in a metric space. I'm wondering what is the correct way to establish the continuity on every point in the metric space from the theorems of continuity on a single point?

Comment: Set up the test for an arbitrary point and see if it holds.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I just realized the theorems for continuity on a point seem to be for an arbitrary point. Does my such realization sound to be on the right track?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are not trying to prove uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a function from a metric space $X$ to another metric space $Y$ with $d_X$ denoting the metric on $X$ and $Y$ the metric on $Y$. We say that $f$ is continuous in $p\in X$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such $d_Y(f(x), f(p)) < \varepsilon$ for every $x\in X$ with $d_X(x,p)<\delta$.

**Example.** Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. Recall that the canonical metric on $\mathbb R$ is defined by $d(x,y) = | x -y|$. To prove that $f$ is in fact continuous in every $p\in \mathbb R$ on this metric space, consider an arbitrary $p\in \mathbb R$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, $$\begin{align*}d_Y(f(x),f(p)) &= \left|f(x) - f(p) \right| \\ &= \left|(x^2 + 1) - (p^2 +1)\right|\\ &= \left| x^2 - p^2\right| \\ &= \left| (x - p)(x + p)\right|\\ &= \left|(x-p)(x - p + p + p)\right|\\ &= \left|x-p\right|\left|x - p + 2p\right| \\ &\leq\left| x - p\right| (\left| x - p \right| + \left| 2p\right|) \\ &=\left|x - p\right|^2 + \vert x -p\vert\left| 2p\right| \\ & < \delta^2+\delta\left| 2p\right|,\end{align*}$$
by applying the Triangle inequality and the assumption $d_X(x,p) = |x - p|<\delta$. If there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\vert 2p\vert\leq\varepsilon/2$ and $\delta^2<\varepsilon/2$, we have proven that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$. That is, $f$ is continuous in $p$. Clearly, chosing $$\delta = \max\left\{\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}},\frac{\varepsilon}{|4p|}\right\}$$ yields the desired result (if $p=0$, we can chose any $\delta<\varepsilon$).

I hope the example makes clear how to show continuity of a function.

Comment: Could you plz share some hint for deriving the same inequality from the canonical metric of R^2? Thanks!

Comment: For deriving the inequality from the canonical metric of $R^2$, I got $x-a < sqrt(\delta^2 - (y - b)^2)$, and b is just the y-value of arbitrary point. Can I simplify what I've got?

Comment: What's the function? The canonical metric on $\mathbb R^2$ is $d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}$. So there is no "standard" way of proceeding as it depends on the function of interest